# Will the Radeon HD 7670M + 7670M Dual Graphics Work Well With Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, hardware

I have just recently purchased the HP Pavilion M6 15.6" Laptop - Silver (AMD A10-4600M / 1TB HDD / 8GB RAM / Windows 8). This laptop has a AMD Radeon HD 7670M + 7670M Dual Graphics.I am having some troubles with my photoshop CS5. The grey screen when opening a new file keeps flickering between a checkerboard backround and the grey backround. Does this have anything to do with the graphics card if so what graphics card should I upgrade to. Or is it just simply windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

The main problems with Photoshop in Windows 8 have to do with the display drivers not being up to snuff for facilitating the GPU acceleration Photoshop needs.

Watch the web site of the maker of your video card (would that be ATI?  AMD.com then) for driver updates.

As a workaround you might consider going into Edit - Preferences - Performance, entering the [Advanced Settings] for the GPU, and reducing the mode to Basic.  In an extreme case you could consider disabling the [  ] Use Graphics Processor setting entirely.